# Azure Container App Job on a event trigger executes every pooling interval instead of when a new message arrives in queue

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps, dapr, azure-container-app-jobs

I have a container app job with an event trigger that should only execute when a new message is in a blob storage queue. However it executes on every pooling interval (i have set it to 5 minutes), which just consumes additional resources without processing anything. Below is my JSON configuration of the job:

```json
{
    "id": "***",
    "name": "***",
    "type": "Microsoft.App/jobs",
    "location": "East US",
    "properties": {
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
        "environmentId": "***",
        "workloadProfileName": "Consumption",
        "configuration": {
            "secrets": [
                {
                    "name": "connection-string-secret"
                },
                {
                    "name": "***"
                }
            ],
            "triggerType": "Event",
            "replicaTimeout": 4000,
            "replicaRetryLimit": 1,
            "manualTriggerConfig": null,
            "scheduleTriggerConfig": null,
            "eventTriggerConfig": {
                "replicaCompletionCount": 1,
                "parallelism": 1,
                "scale": {
                    "minExecutions": 0,
                    "maxExecutions": 2,
                    "pollingInterval": 300,
                    "rules": [
                        {
                            "name": "queue",
                            "type": "azure-queue",
                            "metadata": {
                                "accountName": "***",
                                "queueLength": "1",
                                "queueName": "***"
                            },
                            "auth": [
                                {
                                    "secretRef": "connection-string-secret",
                                    "triggerParameter": "connection"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "registries": [
                {
                    "server": "***.azurecr.io",
                    "username": "***",
                    "passwordSecretRef": "***"
                }
            ],
            "dapr": null
        },
        "template": {
            "containers": [
                {
                    "image": "***.azurecr.io/***:latest",
                    "name": "***_job",
                    "env": [
                        {
                            "name": "AZURE_STORAGE_QUEUE_NAME",
                            "value": "***"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING",
                            "secretRef": "connection-string-secret"
                        }
                    ],
                    "resources": {
                        "cpu": 4,
                        "memory": "8Gi"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "initContainers": null,
            "volumes": null
        },
        "eventStreamEndpoint": "***"
    },
    "identity": {
        "type": "None"
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this could happen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is possible that the polling interval set for the event-driven job is causing it to execute on every interval instead of when a new message arrives in the queue. According to the documentation, if the polling interval is small, updates to the workflow might not take effect for up to 10 minutes. To work around this problem, you can disable the logic app resource, make the changes, and then enable the logic app resource again.

Comment: Another possibility is that the scaling rule for the job is not set up correctly. The scaling rule determines the number of jobs to run based on the volume of events for an event source. If the scaling rule is not set up correctly, it could cause the job to execute on every interval instead of when a new message arrives in the queue.

You may want to review your job configuration and ensure that the scaling rule is set up correctly and that the polling interval is not too small.

Comment: References:

-   [Jobs in Azure Container Apps - Event-driven jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/jobs#job-trigger-types)
-   [Connect to Azure Service Bus from workflows in Azure Logic Apps - Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-servicebus#troubleshooting)
-   [Tutorial: Deploy an event-driven job with Azure Container Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/tutorial-event-driven-jobs#tutorial-deploy-an-event-driven-job-with-azure-container-apps)

Comment: @Arko are there any logs that i can see if the container job cannot connect to the queue and pinpoint the exact problem that way?

Comment: After 5 times of deleting the container job and recreating it again, the problem   came out to be with the blob storage queue instead. It would be helpful if azure could provide some logs for this but for other people having this problem:
- Delete the storage queue
- Recreate it with the following command:
```bash
az storage queue create --name "<QUEUE>" --account-name "<BLOB_STORAGE_NAME>" --connection-string "<CONNECTION_STRING>"
```
the `<CONNECTION_STRING>` should be the same as the one you put for the `connection-string-secret` in the container app job